# Unable to save binary data into AWS S3 from jQuery

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, html5-audio, getusermedia

I'm trying to upload a `Blob` object into S3, which does get uploaded but in a corrupted way. The application is about recording `audio` on a web page and saving it to S3.

HTML + Javascript Code:

```
        <p>
            <button id=startRecord>START</button>
            <button id=stopRecord disabled>Submit</button>
        </p>
        <p id="recording"></p>
        <p>
            <a id=audioDownload></a>
        </p>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var audioContent;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
    .then(stream => {
        rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        rec.ondataavailable = e => {
            audioChunks.push(e.data);
            if (rec.state == "inactive"){
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks);
            // audioContent = blob
            // audioContent = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(audioChunks));
            // console.log(audioContent);

                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: 'https://aws-api-url/prod/audio',
                  data: new Blob(audioChunks),
                  crossDomain: true,
                  processData: false,
                  headers: {"x-api-key": 'someKey'},
                  contentType: false
                });
        // audioDownload.href = audioContent;
        // audioDownload.download = 'test';
        // audioDownload.innerHTML = 'download';
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log(e));

startRecord.onclick = e => {
  startRecord.disabled = true;
  stopRecord.disabled=false;
  document.getElementById("recording").innerHTML = "Listening...";
  audioChunks = [];
  rec.start();
}
stopRecord.onclick = e => {
    document.getElementById("recording").innerHTML = "";
  startRecord.disabled = false;
  stopRecord.disabled=true;
  rec.stop();
}
</script>
```

AWS Lambda that dumps into S3

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='',aws_secret_access_key='')

    s3_client.put_object(Body=event['body'], Bucket='bucket', Key='incoming/test.wav')

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
       'headers': {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': json.dumps(event)
    }
```

What changes can I possibly make into my Javascript to send this data safely

Answer (score 0):

[MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder) does not generate the .wav data type. By default it probably generates data of the [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/mimeType) `audio/webm; codecs=opus`. or `audio/ogg; codec=vorbis`.  Your lambda function looks like it faithfully stores the incoming data. But it's not .wav data, it's something else.

Your sample code lets MediaRecorder choose its own MIME type. In this case you should ask it what it used. For example

```
rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
console.log (rec.mimeType);
```

Or, you can (try to) tell it the MIME type you want. In this case you should still ask it what it actually used. (Browsers vary in the MIME types they generate, and in the ways they respond when they can't deliver the exact type you want.) If your browser can do it, this code will *probably* [generate mp3 (aka MPEG Layer III) audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers#MPEG).

```
rec = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: "audio/mpeg"});
console.log (rec.mimeType);
```

Or, you can try the [`audio/mp4` MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers#MP4), and see what audio codec you get. It may vary from browser to browser.

You can generally use [ffmpeg](https://linuxconfig.org/ffmpeg-audio-format-conversions) to convert any MIME type to another once you've recorded it. This is handy if require .wav output, or some other particular format. [It takes some hacking, but you can do it in your lambda function](https://intoli.com/blog/transcoding-on-aws-lambda/).

Comment: I did fix this `mimeType` problem, however the problem persists. I found out thath the lambda function is reading is my `event['body']` as `str`, not sure if that is the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with python-language AWS lambda endpoints. But, I believe AWS hands you the binary payload of your POST operation encoded as a base64 text string. You need to use `base64.b64decode()` to turn it into a binary object. See this:: https://medium.com/swlh/upload-binary-files-to-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-with-aws-lambda-2b4ba8c70b8e